# Using JOIN to match 1st result

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I'm trying to obtain the price from a field called `DiscountMarkupPriceRate1` on my second table to display in PHP.

The first portion of my query pulls what I need correctly, the `Parentsku` of all visible products with inventory. ie GTR101.

I'm trying to join it with a second table and retrieve only the first `DiscountMarkupPriceRate1` for the parent (GTR101%) where `ItemCustomerPriceLevel` is `M`.

Here's what my table looks like. This is essentially the result of the first half of my query before the join (stripped of all the other fields I need):

```
**INVENTORY**
SKU      store_quantity     parent_sku  visible
----------------------------------------------------------------
GTR101      20      NULL        Y
GTR102      100     NULL        Y
GTR103      88      NULL        Y
```

This is the second table:

```
**ins_imb_1**

DiscountMarkupPriceRate1    ItemNumber   ItemCustomerPriceLevel           
-----------------------------------------------------------------
15.950             GTR101S          M
15.950             GTR101M          M
11.950             GTR101L          M
10.000             GTR101S          T
```

I'm trying to get

```
GTR101   15.95
```

and here's what I have for a query:

```
Select * 
from INVENTORY
where parent_sku='' 
AND store_quantity > 0 
AND SKU like '%GTR%' 
AND visible='Y'

LEFT JOIN ins_imb_1
ON ins_imb_1.ItemNumber =
    (
    SELECT ItemNumber, ItemCustomerPriceLevel, DiscountMarkupPriceRate1
    FROM ins_imb_1
    WHERE ins_imb_1.ItemNumber% = INVENTORY.SKU 
    AND ins_imb_1.ItemCustomerPriceLevel = 'M'
    ORDER BY 
            INVENTORY.SKU
    LIMIT 1
    )
```

Comment: I suggest storing the `ItemNumber` as `GTR101`, and storing the `S` or `M` or `L` in its own field.

Comment: "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, " boolean given in"  is the PHP error, but in PHPMYADMIN I just don't get any results.

Comment: The PHP errors mean the query failed.  You should really check if the result is `FALSE` if so, print out `mysql_error()`.

Comment: I don't have control over the database structure, the parent site for it was built in PERL but I'm trying to get my result in PHP.  I don't know PERL  but this is what the original developer left as a 'workaround'. NOt sure if it will help anyone:  
 <%print inventory::get_price($ITEM{SKU});%>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing wrong I see here, is that `JOIN`s need to be after the FROM statement and before WHERE.

Also your subquery in the LEFT JOIN is wrong.

```
LEFT JOIN ins_imb_1
ON ins_imb_1.ItemNumber =
(
  SELECT ItemNumber, ItemCustomerPriceLevel, DiscountMarkupPriceRate1
```

Your subquery should only return one field (for it to compare to `ins_imb_1.ItemNumber`).

I don't know if you even need a subquery here, you could do something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN ins_imb_1
ON ins_imb_1.ItemNumber LIKE CONCAT(INVENTORY.SKU, '%')
AND ins_imb_1.ItemCustomerPriceLevel = 'M'
```

I also see few things that could be optimized here.

`where parent_sku=''` should be `where parent_sku IS NULL`.

`AND SKU like '%GTR%'` should be `AND SKU like 'GTR%'`(as the SKU always start with 'GTR').

```
SELECT *
FROM INVENTORY

LEFT JOIN ins_imb_1
ON ins_imb_1.ItemNumber LIKE CONCAT(INVENTORY.SKU, '%')
AND ins_imb_1.ItemCustomerPriceLevel = 'M'

WHERE parent_sku IS NULL
AND store_quantity > 0
AND SKU LIKE 'GTR%'
AND visible = 'Y'
```

Comment: Wow I see why your name is Rocket!! That did it, however apparently I lied, because the parent_sku field is just empty not NULL. But once I change that back it pulls exactly the result I was looking for!  And thank for the better understanding as well, when reading it aloud I guess it makes sense for the WHERE clause to follow the JOIN.